# i want max of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

Requirement is i need
ID,Date and max value from A to I column.
MAX value from columns A,B,C,D,E,F,G,   I need SQL server  or Synapse query

[image]

already tried

```
select max(A) from (values( A,B,C,D,E,F,G, I)) as A) as Z
```

this is working with sql but not with Azure synapse

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: `...from (values( A,B,C,D,E,F,G, I)) as t(A)) as Z`?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.max_val
from t cross apply
     (select max(v.col) as max_val
      from (values (a), (b), . . .) v(col)
     ) v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Serverless SQL pools (formerly known as SQL on-demand) in Azure Synapse Analytics supports `GREATEST` so this type of query is easy in serverless, eg

```
SELECT id, dt, GREATEST ( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) x
FROM yourTable
```

For dedicated SQL pools you can use `UNPIVOT` for the same effect:

```
SELECT id, dt, MAX(x) x
FROM yourTable
UNPIVOT ( x for y In ( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) ) AS upvt
GROUP BY id, dt
```

`GREATEST` *may* get added at some point for dedicated SQL pools so it's probably worth checking every now and then.

Another thing you could do, as SparkSQL supports `GREATEST` is use an Azure Synapse notebook to quickly pull the data over from the dedicated SQL pool, process it and pop it back, say as part of a batch process.  Here's a simple example using a Scala notebook.

Cell1:

```
// Get the table from the dedicated SQL pool into a dataframe
val df = spark.read.synapsesql("someSQLPool.dbo.greatestWorking")

// Save the dataframe as a temp view to make it available to SparkSQL
df.createOrReplaceTempView("greatestWorking")
```

Cell 2:

```
// Write the result to a new data frame to be saved back into the dedicated SQL pool
val result = spark.sql("SELECT id, dt, GREATEST ( a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i ) AS x FROM greatestWorking") 

result.write.synapsesql("someSQLPool.dbo.result", Constants.INTERNAL)
```